getElementsByTagName throws Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A138A
What could be the reason that Powershell would throw Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A138A
For this script:
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $Url
[array]$x = $response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('devsite-content') | Select -ExpandProperty outerHTML

I am running the script on a Windows 11 64-bit machine.
